# Scrapy hxs.select() not selecting all results

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrapy to scrape odds from [here](http://www.paddypower.com/football/football-matches/premier-league).

Currently just trying to log the results with the following spider :

```
def parse(self, response):         
   log.start("LogFile.txt", log.DEBUG);

   hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
   sites = hxs.select('//div[@class="fb_day_type_wrapper"]')

   items = []
   for site in sites:
       siteAddress = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, site.extract())
       self.log('Found category url: %s' % siteAddress)
```

This only logs the entry: This market is currently unavailable....
Not the other elements which contain the odds.

I have tried a few different selectors with no luck. It looks like once I try and get inside of the element `div[@class="fb_day_type_wrapper"]` I get nothing returned. I have the same results using the scrapy shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The site uses javascript to generate the data table. There are some alternatives like [scrapyjs](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs) or [splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) that allows to get the js-rendered html page. If you only need to scrape one page, you might be better off using Selenium.

Otherwise, you might need to go into hardcore mode and reverse engineer what is going on in the site with the data. I will show you how to do that.

First, start the `scrapy shell` so we can explore the web page:

```
scrapy shell http://www.paddypower.com/football/football-matches/premier-league
```

**Note:** I'm using python 2.7.4, ipython 0.13.2 and scrapy 0.18.0.

If you lookup in the source for "Crystal Palace v Fulham" in your browser, you will see there is a javascript code that have that reference. The `<script>` block looks like:

```
document.bodyOnLoad.push(function() {
    lb_fb_cpn_init(
        "",
        "html",
        "MR_224",
        {category: 'SOCCER',
```

We lookup in the shell for this element:

```
In [1]: hxs.select('//script[contains(., "lb_fb_cpn_init")]')
Out[1]: [<HtmlXPathSelector xpath='//script[contains(., "lb_fb_cpn_init")]' data=u'<script type="text/javascript">\n/* $Id: '>]
```

If you lookup into the `lb_fb_cpn_init` arguments, you will see the data we are looking for is passed as an argument in this form:

```
[{names: {en: 'Newcastle v Liverpool'}, ...
```

In fact there are three arguments like that:

```
In [2]: hxs.select('//script[contains(., "lb_fb_cpn_init")]').re('\[{names:')
Out[2]: [u'[{names:', u'[{names:', u'[{names:']
```

So we extract all of them, notice that we use a lot of regular expressions:

```
In [3]: js_args = hxs.select('//script[contains(., "lb_fb_cpn_init")]').re(r'(\[{names:(?:.+?)\]),')

In [4]: len(js_args)
Out[4]: 3
```

The idea here is that we want to parse the javascript code (which is a literal object) into python code (a dict). We could use `json.loads` but to do so the js code must be a valid json object, that is, have field names and strings enclosed in `""`.

We proceed to do so. First I join the arguments in a single string as a javascript list:

```
In [5]: args_raw = '[{}]'.format(', '.join(js_args))
```

Then we enclose the field names into `""` **and** replace with single quotes with double quotes:

```
In [6]: import re

In [7]: args_json = re.sub(r'(,\s?|{)(\w+):', r'\1"\2":', args_raw).replace("'", '"')
```

This might not always work in all cases as the javascript code might have patterns that are not so easy to replace with a single `re.sub` and/or `.replace`.

We are ready to parse the javascript code as a json object:

```
In [8]: import json

In [9]: data = json.loads(args_json)

In [10]: len(data)
Out[10]: 3
```

Here, I'm just looking for the event name and odds. You can take a look to the `data` content to see what it looks like.

Luckily, the data seems to have a correlation:

```
In [11]: map(len, data)
Out[11]: [20, 20, 60]
```

You could as well build a single `dict` from the three of them by using the `ev_id` field. I will just assume that `data[0]` and `data[1]` hava a direct correlation and that `data[2]` contains 3 items per event. This can be easily verified with:

```
In [12]: map(lambda v: v['ev_id'], data[2])
Out [12]:
[5889932,
 5889932,
 5889932,
 5889933,
 5889933,
 5889933,
 ...
```

With some python-fu, we can merge the records:

```
In [13]: odds = iter(data[2])

In [14]: odds_merged = zip(odds, odds, odds)

In [15]: data_merged = zip(data[0], data[1], odds_merged)

In [16]: len(data_merged)
Out[16]: 20
```

Finally, we collect the data:

```
In [17]: get_odd = lambda obj: (obj['names']['en'], '/'.join([obj['lp_num'], obj['lp_den']]))

In [18]: event_odds = []

In [19]: for event, _, odds in data_merged:
   ....:     event_odds.append({'name': event['names']['en'], 'odds': dict(map(get_odd, odds)), 'url': event['url']})
   ....:     

In [20]: event_odds
Out[20]: 
[{'name': u'Newcastle v Liverpool',
  'odds': {u'Draw': u'14/5', u'Liverpool': u'17/20', u'Newcastle': u'3/1'},
  'url': u'http://www.paddypower.com/football/football-matches/premier-league-matches/Newcastle%2dv%2dLiverpool-5889932.html'},
 {'name': u'Arsenal v Norwich',
  'odds': {u'Arsenal': u'3/10', u'Draw': u'9/2', u'Norwich': u'9/1'},
  'url': u'http://www.paddypower.com/football/football-matches/premier-league-matches/Arsenal%2dv%2dNorwich-5889933.html'},
 {'name': u'Chelsea v Cardiff',
  'odds': {u'Cardiff': u'10/1', u'Chelsea': u'1/4', u'Draw': u'5/1'},
  'url': u'http://www.paddypower.com/football/football-matches/premier-league-matches/Chelsea%2dv%2dCardiff-5889934.html'},
 {'name': u'Everton v Hull',
  'odds': {u'Draw': u'10/3', u'Everton': u'4/9', u'Hull': u'13/2'},
  'url': u'http://www.paddypower.com/football/football-matches/premier-league-matches/Everton%2dv%2dHull-5889935.html'},
 {'name': u'Man Utd v Southampton',
  'odds': {u'Draw': u'3/1', u'Man Utd': u'8/15', u'Southampton': u'11/2'},
  'url': u'http://www.paddypower.com/football/football-matches/premier-league-matches/Man%2dUtd%2dv%2dSouthampton-5889939.html'},
 ...
```

As you can see, web scraping can be very challenging (and fun!). All it depends how the website displays the data. Here you could save time by just using Selenium, but if you are looking to scrape a large website, Selenium will be very slow compared to Scrapy.

Also you have to consider whether the site will get code updates very often, in that case you will spend more time reverse engineering the js code. In that case a solution like [scrapyjs](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs) or [splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) can be a better option.

Final remarks:

- Now you have all the code required to extract the data. You need to integrate this into your spider callback and build your item.
- Don't use `log.start`. Use the setting `LOG_FILE` (command line argument: `--set LOG_FILE=mylog.txt`).
- Remeber that `.extract()` always returns a list.